# Search a fixed amount of documents over a period of time in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, query-optimization

We have a database with a lot of documents, which gets bigger as time goes on. Right now, query time isn't a problem since the data is only ~1 year old or so. But the bigger this gets, the longer queries will take if we query everything.

Our idea was to take every nth document, the more documents there are, you leave some data out, but you still get a good image from data over the time. However, this is hard to do in Mongo and doesn't seem to work at all, since it still traverses all documents.

Is there a way to set a fixed query time, no matter how many documents, or at least reduce it? It doesn't matter if we lose data overall, as long as we get documents from every time range.

Comment: Do you guys use indexes on the fields you query?

Comment: yep, we do @AlexP.

Comment: You can aggregate your data monthly by using the aggregation framework. So if you want to query the complete time range your data is pre aggregated and you don't lose anything.

Comment: You mean, aggregate all documents per month, and query on that? Is aggregation so much faster than a query over every document? Sorry, im still pretty new to mongo

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly how your data looks like, but here is an example of what I mean. Let's assume this is your data stored in the database.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e272e74d8a2fe38b86187d"),
    "name" : "data1",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-07T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "number" : 15
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e272e74d8a2fe38b86187f"),
    "name" : "data2",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-11-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "number" : 19
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e272e74d8a2fe38b861881"),
    "name" : "data3",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-10-06T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "number" : 20
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59e272e74d8a2fe38b861883"),
    "name" : "data4",
    "date" : ISODate("2017-10-05T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "number" : 65
}
```

I understand you want to compare some values throughout months or even years. So you could do the following

```
db.getCollection('test').aggregate([
{
    $match: {
        // query on the fields with index
        date: {$gte: ISODate("2017-10-05 00:00:00.000Z"), 
               $lte: ISODate("2017-11-07 00:00:00.000Z")}
    }
},
{
    // retrieve the month from each document
    $project: {
        _id: 1,
        name: 1,
        date: 1,
        number: 1,
        month: {$month: "$date"}
    }
},
{
    // group them by month and perform some accumulator operation
    $group: {
        _id: "$month",
        name: {$addToSet: "$name"},
        dateFrom: {$min: "$date"},
        dateTo: {$max: "$date"},
        number: {$sum: "$number"}
    }
}
])
```

I would suggest you save the pre aggregated data, this way instead of searching through 30 documents per month for example you'd only need to search for 1 per month. And you'd only have to aggregate the complete data only once, if you have the pre aggregated results stored then you'd only have to run the pre aggregation for the new data that are coming in.

Is that maybe something you are looking for?

Also if you have indexes and they fields you query have indexes then this helps as well. Otherwise MongoDB has to scan every document in a collection.